# Вопрос по PHP, внесение из базы в массив

Tags: php, mysql

Вопрос заключается в следующем: Имеем скрипт (ниже).

Зачем в этом случае записывать массив в переменную $array 2 раза, если можно просто запись произвести в цикле, и почему в этом случае выводится блок с пустым содержимым 7-м блоком?

```
        $per_page = 6;

        if (isset($_GET['page'])) $page=($_GET['page']-1); else $page=0;

        $start=abs($page*$per_page);

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `news` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start,$per_page");
        $array = mysql_fetch_array($result);


        do
        {
        echo ""."<a href='/newsfull.php/?single=$array[id]' class='news-block'><img class='news-img' src='statimg/$array[file]' alt=''><div class='news-content'><h4>". $array[zagolovok] . "</h4><p>" . $array[smallopisanie] . "</p><p style='text-align: right; display: block;'>" . $array[time] . " <i class='fa fa-calendar-o' aria-hidden='true'></i></p></div></a>"."";
        }
        while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

Мои предположения относительно переработки скрипта, хочу узнать почему так не работает:

```
            include 'bd.php';

            $per_page = 6;

            if (isset($_GET['page'])) $page=($_GET['page']-1); else $page=0;

            $start=abs($page*$per_page);

            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `news` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start,$per_page");


            do
            {
            echo ""."<a href='/newsfull.php/?single=$array[id]' class='news-block'><img class='news-img' src='statimg/$array[file]' alt=''><div class='news-content'><h4>". $array[zagolovok] . "</h4><p>" . $array[smallopisanie] . "</p><p style='text-align: right; display: block;'>" . $array[time] . " <i class='fa fa-calendar-o' aria-hidden='true'></i></p></div></a>"."";
            }
            while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вся соль в этом куске кода

```
  do
            {
            echo ""."<a href='/newsfull.php/?single=$array[id]' class='news-block'><img class='news-img' src='statimg/$array[file]' alt=''><div class='news-content'><h4>". $array[zagolovok] . "</h4><p>" . $array[smallopisanie] . "</p><p style='text-align: right; display: block;'>" . $array[time] . " <i class='fa fa-calendar-o' aria-hidden='true'></i></p></div></a>"."";
            }
            while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

Сначала Вы выводите, а потом запрашиваете данные для вывода, в результате у Вас 1 блок пустой (без данных), для того что бы работало нормально

```
  while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
            echo ""."<a href='/newsfull.php/?single=$array[id]' class='news-block'><img class='news-img' src='statimg/$array[file]' alt=''><div class='news-content'><h4>". $array[zagolovok] . "</h4><p>" . $array[smallopisanie] . "</p><p style='text-align: right; display: block;'>" . $array[time] . " <i class='fa fa-calendar-o' aria-hidden='true'></i></p></div></a>"."";
            }
```

Рекомендую ознакомится с справкой

do {} while (); http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.do.while.php

и while() {} http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.while.php

Принцип похож но имеет различия во времени проверки условий выполнения циклов

Comment: Ну, как я понял он сначала вывел первый блок, а потом уже в переменную $array записались условия которые были даны выше, верно?

Comment: Да, но при этом данные для первого блока, на момент его вывода отсутствовали. Данные Вы получили когда сделали проверку while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($result)); По простому в 1-м варианте вы сразу выводили, потом получали что выводить и проверяли можно ли выводить, когда данные не были получены происходил выход из цыкла. В итоге на 6 записей делали 7 выводов. Во втором варианте, сразу получаете данные, проверялается возможность вывода и происходит вывод (на 6 записей - 6 выводов данных)